# Extending one class inside other class in php

Tags: php, multithreading, inheritance

I have a class A which extends class B as following

```
Class A extends B
{


    function SendMAil(){

    /* Here Send Mail Code is wriiten */ 

    }

}
```

and I have another class C in which i have implemented multithreading concept, for which i need to extedn C frrom Thread

```
Class C extends Thread {


  function SendMail2(){

  /* Code For SendMail2() */


  }

}
```

Now i need to extends Thread Class also in class A, So that i can use the functionality of multithreading in class A, how can i do this

PS : Class Thread is a inbuilt class in php when we install a pthread library for PHP so we can not do any alteration in class Thread.

I stuck there !! How can i do this??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: what is class B here ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use traits then. Trait are a lot like classes, but they are most likely used to just bundle things you need a lot and which have a relationship to each other.

For example:

```
trait ThreadTrait {
    public function doSomeMultithreading() {
        // Put your multithreading code in here
    }
}

Class A extends B {
    use ThreadTrait;

    public function aFunctionWhereYouCanUseMultithreadingNow() {
        echo 'Multithreading possible in every class now!:)';
    }
}
```

Now you can access all needed functions for your multithreading in every Class you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can extends class `B` with class `Thread` first then extends the class `A` with class `B`. You will get all public and protected members of `Thread` class available in class `B`.
Like this:

```
<?php 
class Thread {
    public function threadfunc() {
        echo "This is thread class";
    }
}
class B extends Thread {
    public function bfunc()
    {
        $this->threadfunc();
    }
}
Class A extends B {
    function SendMAil(){
        echo "sendmail";
    }
}
Class C extends Thread {
    function SendMail2(){
        echo "send mail 2";
    }

}
$obj = new A();
$obj->bfunc();
```

Comment: Note that you can indent your code using 4 spaces to show up as code (or highlight your code and press Ctrl+K). I've done this for you, but next time take a look at the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Traits are of no use here, since they cannot be composed of anything but other traits; a trait cannot `extend` a class, but only `use` other traits.

The inheritance you describe is quite strange, regardless of pthreads.

With regard to pthreads, objects that are `Threaded` have different semantics than normal PHP objects, normal PHP objects are not well prepared for threading which is the *very good* reason you need to declare that classes descend from `pthreads` when they are intended to be used in multi-threaded code.

So, an example; because A, B and C are a little abstract ;)

If we imagine that your backend application is responsible for registering new users; updating database and sending out emails, and creating their kitten avatars (obviously), and doing some other heavy lifting.

We'll make the assumptions that:

- somewhere in your application you have a `Pool`, because that's be good practice,
- you have some classes designed to do background work (`Threaded`)
- you have some normal PHP classes doing normal things

## Mailer

*The code that is threaded*

```
class Mailer extends Threaded {

    public function __construct($email, $subject, $message) {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    public function send() {
        if (!mail($this->email, $this->subject, $this->message)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(
                "the mailman is a failure ...");
        }
    }

    public function run() {
        /* when I am submitted to a 
            Pool or Worker, I will send the email */
        $this->send();
        /* alternatively, Mailer could be a Thread
            but I won't encourage you to be wasteful ;) */
    }

    protected $email;
    protected $subject;
    protected $message;
}
```

## Arbitrary Code

*Application code that is not threaded*

```
class Something {
    public function thing() {

    }
}
```

## Application Code

*Code that uses arbitrary and threaded code*

```
class Register {

    public function __construct(Pool $pool, Mailer $mail, Something $some) {
        $this->pool = $pool;
        $this->mail = $mail;
        $this->some = $some;
    }

    public function doRegistration() {
        /* ... do registration things ... */
        $this->some->thing();

        /* send the email in the background */
        $this->pool
            ->submit($this->mail);

        /* do the next thing */
        $this->some->thing();
    }

    protected $pool;
    protected $mail;
    protected $other;
}
```

## Example

```
/* somewhere else in the application */
$pool     = new Pool(2);
$some     = new Something();

/* here */
$mail     = new Mailer("krakjoe@php.net", "oi", "look here");
$register = new Register($pool, $mail, $some);
$register->doRegistration();

/* somewhere else suitable in the application */
$pool->shutdown();
```

http://pastebin.com/PvaZr2pH

*Note: it is not necessary to send email in a background thread, this is example code only*

Further reading:

- https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782
- https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/9384409
- http://php.net/pthreads